# Property 'map' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<Action, never>'.ts(2339)

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ngrx

I'm new to ngrx and following a not that old tutorial but it seems the way "map", "ofType", "of" and "pipe" are used, have changed, so "map" and "of" are throwing errors

"map" error :  Property 'map' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction'.ts(2339)

and

"of" error://  Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.ts(2339)

Here is the Action:

```
export class GetUser implements Action {
     readonly type = GET_USER;
     constructor(public payload?: any) { }
}
```

Hereis the Effect:

```
@Effect()
 getUser: Observable<Action> = this.actions.pipe(ofType(userActions.GET_USER)
      **.map**((action: userActions.GetUser) => action.payload)
      .switchMap(payload => this.afAuth.authState)
      .delay(2000)
      .map(authData => {
           if (authData) {
                const user = new User(authData.uid, authData.displayName);
                return new userActions.Authenticated(user);
           } else {
                return new userActions.NotAuthenticated();
           }
      }).catch(err => Observable.**of**(new userActions.AuthError()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this is using an older version of RxJS.
Since version 6 (I believe), pipeable operators should be used.
These are imported from `'rxjs/operators'`, e.g. `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`

```
@Effect()
 getUser: Observable<Action> = this.actions.pipe(ofType(userActions.GET_USER)
      ,map((action: userActions.GetUser) => action.payload)
      ,switchMap(payload => this.afAuth.authState)
      ,delay(2000)
      ,map(authData => {
           if (authData) {
                const user = new User(authData.uid, authData.displayName);
                return new userActions.Authenticated(user);
           } else {
                return new userActions.NotAuthenticated();
           }
      });
```

See the docs https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, they changed in RxJS v6, I think it was. Now many of them are considered "pipeable" operators meaning that they are passed into the `pipe` method as arguments instead of the chaining like you're doing here. Your code should look more like:

```
@Effect()
 getUser: Observable<Action> = this.actions.pipe(
     ofType(userActions.GET_USER),
     map((action: userActions.GetUser) => action.payload),
     switchMap(payload => this.afAuth.authState),
     debounceTime(2000),
     map(authData => {
           if (authData) {
                const user = new User(authData.uid, authData.displayName);
                return new userActions.Authenticated(user);
           } else {
                return new userActions.NotAuthenticated();
           }
      }),
      catch(err => of(new userActions.AuthError())
    )
 );
```

I'm not sure why the delay was in there, but it sounds like you want to pause for 2000 milliseconds before continuing so I replaced that method with debounceTime.

Also, if you're using VS Code, get the latest Angular Essentials extension and it will help you with the imports.

Methods like `map` and `switchMap` will be imported from rxjs/operators while creation methods like `of` will be imported from rxjs